# Importance Of Document Continuity & Chapter Interrelationships

Tags: file, size, document, continuity

If I have a large document, such as a book, with chapters that build on and reference each other, do I lose their interrelationships by breaking up the document?  I am working in the Lite version and am curious as to whether to break up a large pdf into smaller doc or pdf files or to keep it intact.  The limitation on the number of characters (50,000) may drive me to another plan.

Comment: What kind of doc is it ? Word doc ? If yes, you could use the Word master/slave mechanism to break your large document into smaller parts, while keeping their interrelationships.

Comment: Thanks, Romain.  Some docs are Word - I will look into the master/slave mechanism.  Some are Adobe or html.  I assume, from your response, that without something like a master/slave mechanism that the interrelationships are lost.  Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know how to split an existing pdf document and update all links to take the new documents organization into account. Parsing/modifying pdf files are not easy tasks. Many information are lost in the pdf, since PDF content is all about graphic stuff. It is hard to detect a heading, to extract the text in the right order, and so on...Usually, pdf documents are generated by a tool. Could they be generated directly with the right file organization instead of splitting a huge pdf into smaller ones in a second time?

Comment: Thanks, again, Romain.  I think the right answer is to convert a pdf to a doc and us the Word master/slave mechanism.